# C# Xamarin does not receive response from HttpClient

Tags: c#, xamarin, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following method in C# Xamarin for authentication:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> _SendAsync(HttpMethod method, string url, object obj)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._AuthToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", this._AuthToken);
        }
        return await this._Client.SendAsync(request);
    }
```

The server receives the request, and the authentication is success (appears in server log). Based on wireshark, many response arrives back from the server, but the function is not returning. The application freezes.

Any idea?
This method is working on a normal console client without any problem.

No error message, just a freezed client.

Thanks your answer!

Comment: How do you call `_SendAsync`? Also, why don't you just return the Task from `SendAsync` instead of awaiting it when there is no need to await it immediately? Just remove the async keyword from the signature and the await. Yields, a similar result, just with less wrapping. But I assume the issue is in the code where you actually call `_SendAsync`, it is probably called wrong and can't return to the context it came from, causing a dead-lock.

Comment: this._Client is an instance of HttpClient object. I forgot writing and ambigous as per the name is the same. HttpClient has only SendAsync method, but I will try.

Comment: @Cheesebaron: can you please comment as Answer? I would like to accept is, but I cannot if it is only a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing here is a classical case of dead-locking. In the comments I suggested to simply remove the `async` and `await` keywords and simply returning the `Task` the `HttpClient.SendAsync` method returns. Why does this change anything? Let me explain.

Right before you `await` a async method the current `SynchronizationContext` is captured. In your case, it is probably the UI Thread.

Then when the actual `SendAsync` method is done doing its work, it will try to return to that `SynchronizationContext`. This is usually fine. However, it really depends on how you actually call the encapsulating method.

If you do something like: `_SendAsync(..).Result` from a UI thread, this will most likely result in a dead-lock. Since the `.Result` is a blocking call the UI thread will wait for `.Result` to finish. Since, the UI thread is waiting, returning to the UI Thread `SynchronizationContext` after the awaited `SendAsync` method is done won't work because the UI Thread is blocked.

So what does simply returning the Task in this case do? Since you are not awaiting the Task and the method isn't marked async, the responsibility of the context switching is moved up the stack to where `_SendAsync` is called. Calling `.Result` here won't do the context switching, but just make a blocking call and losing all the benefits of doing async/await to begin with.

Alternatively, you could also add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to the awaited `this._Client.SendAsync()` call. What this does, is to not return to the capture `SynchronizationContext` and just return to whatever ThreadPool thread it was executed on.

In either case, be very careful with using `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, in most cases it should be avoided.

Tasks should normally be awaited. Or if you don't really care about the result you can fire and forget with `Task.Run()`.

Most service calls and async calls that don't need to return to the captured context, can mostly be post-fixed with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. The main reason to not have it is if you want to update UI just after.

You can read much more about [`ConfigureAwait` in the FAQ by Stepen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

I highly recommend you read the excellent documentation about [async/await in the MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

TL;DR:

Either do:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> _SendAsync(HttpMethod method, string url, object obj)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._AuthToken))
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", this._AuthToken);
    }
    return await this._Client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Or do:

```
private Task<HttpResponseMessage> _SendAsync(HttpMethod method, string url, object obj)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._AuthToken))
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", this._AuthToken);
    }
    return this._Client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

To fix the problem.

And avoid calling `.Result` on Tasks. Always await them.